# NULLIF on timestamp column returning type text

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert to a timestamp type where if empty string, then set value to `NULL`.

example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1jQfNGJ8gexUrtZgp5h63/2

However null seems to be of type text as seen by the error:

`error: column "timestamp_clmn" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text`

How can I use NULLIF on a timestamp field?

Comment: Where is your `NULLIF(a,b)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example:

```
select nullif('','');
 nullif 
--------
 NULL

select pg_typeof(nullif('',''));
 

  pg_typeof 
-----------
 text
```

From the docs [NULLIF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF):

> The result has the same type as the first argument — but there is a subtlety. What is actually returned is the first argument of the implied = operator, and in some cases that will have been promoted to match the second argument's type. For example, NULLIF(1, 2.2) yields numeric, because there is no integer = numeric operator, only numeric = numeric.

So:

```
select nullif('','')::timestamp;
 nullif 
--------
 NULL

select pg_typeof(nullif('','')::timestamp);
          
     pg_typeof          
-----------------------------
 timestamp without time zone
```

You need to cast the text `NULL` to a `timestamp(tz)` one.